# Zsh: Insert active item and hold active in menu select mode

Tags: zsh

I am setting `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select`.

Suppose there are two files `foo1` and `foo2` in a directory. If I type `ls foo<Tab><Tab>` the candidates will be shown in menu mode, which allows me to select item with `<C-n>` or `<C-p>`. And if I press `<M-a>`, the active item will be inserted in the command line and the next item will be active. So it allows me to insert multiple items continuously, but selection moving behavior is not intuitive for me. I want the current item to be still active. Is there any way to accomplish this?